# Subtract an array from another array based on elements in both columns

Tags: matlab

I am looking for an efficient way to do this:

```
(a=1 2; 1 3; 2 3)  - b=(1 2; 2 3) = (c=1 3)
```

or:

```
a=nchoosek([1 2 3 4 5 6],2) - b=(1 2; 1 3; 2 4;3 5;3 6) = (c=1 4;1 5;1 6;2 3;2 5;2 6;3 4;4 5;4 6; 5 6)
```

`a` and `b` will be given and I want to obtain `c`; all data is in double. There will always be two columns.

Comment: Please do not deface your question. This is not fair to the site or the answerer, and in fact, is not allowed per site rules that you agreed to on joining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for an efficient way to do this:
>
> ```
> (a=1 2; 1 3; 2 3)  - b=(1 2; 2 3) = (c=1 3)
> ```

your notation is a bit inconsistent, but it looks you want to understand `a` and `b` as a *set* of tuples of two numbers. That's fine, do just exactly that.

In Python, this would be super easy; I'm only using Python to illustrate the concept[¹](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888594/subtract-an-array-from-another-array-based-on-elements-in-both-columns/69888669#69888669#footnote1):

```
a = {(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)}
b = {(1,2), (2,3)}
c = a - b
```

In matlab, [setdiff](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.setdiff.html) is to be used; basically, you need to have the 2-tuples as *rows* of `a` and `b` (so `a` will be a 3×2 matrix).

---

<sup>¹ That's not 100% true. I'm also here to tell you that if your code depends on Matlab doing a lot of set operations, then you will have a long, slow day of annoying coding, and another one of slow, annoying matlab running. It's really not something matlab is good at, neither from the development perspective, nor from the execution side. Might be worth looking at other tools than matlab!</sup>

Comment: To expand on this answer: in Matlab you would use `A = [1 2; 1 3; 2 3]; B = [1 2; 2 3]; C = setdiff(A, B, 'rows')`

Comment: please don't ask new questions as edits to answered questions. Open a new question post, please!